# Playing .mpg videos in Flash/Actionscript

Tags: flash, video, mpeg

Is it possible to load .mpg file and play it through actionscript/flash ?

The code works well with mp4 video files. If not possible to play mpg files, the one way to make it work is converting these files?

```
package  {
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import se.svt.caspar.template.CasparTemplate;

    public class data extends CasparTemplate {
        var nc:NetConnection;
        var ns:NetStream;
        var vid:Video;
        var textfield:TextField;

        public function data() {

            nc = new NetConnection();
            nc.connect(null);

            ns = new NetStream(nc);
            ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
            ns.play("test3.MPEG");

            vid = new Video();
            vid.attachNetStream(ns);
            addChild(vid);

        }

        function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void
        {
            trace("error");
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash player can play a limited number of video formats : [**Sorenson Spark H263**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorenson_Media#Sorenson_Spark) (FLV), [**On2 VP6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP6) (FLV) and [**H.264**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) (MP4, M4V, F4V, 3GPP).

So for your mpeg video you have to convert it to one of these supported formats.

For more information, you can see [supported codecs for flash player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/supported-codecs-flash-player.html) and here to [understand more video formats](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d46.html), also you can take a look on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video#Media_type_support).