# Video not showing using netstream(bytes)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, flash-cs4

im working on video streaming i have a php api that return the video and then play it using byte array,but video is not showing, but when i look at the trace is hows the downloaded bytes and bytesloaded.Can you give me idea what i'm doing wrong i'm new in actionscript.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.net.NetStreamAppendBytesAction;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLStream;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;


    var video:Video;
    var video_nc:NetConnection;
    var video_ns:NetStream;

    var video_stream:URLStream; 

    video_nc = new NetConnection();
    video_nc.connect(null);

    video_ns = new NetStream(video_nc);
    video_ns.client = this;
    video_ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, ns_statusHandler);

    video = new Video(1280, 720);
    video.attachNetStream(video_ns);
    video.smoothing = true;

    video_ns.play(null);
    video_ns.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);

    video_stream = new URLStream();
    video_stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, videoStream_progressHandler);

    video_stream.load(new URLRequest("https://www.xxxx.com/test.php"));

    addChild(video);


    function ns_statusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void
    {
        trace(event.info.code);
        trace("zzz");
    }

    function videoStream_progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        trace(event.bytesLoaded);
        var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

        video_stream.readBytes(bytes);
        video_ns.appendBytes(bytes);
        //trace(bytes);
    }
```

Comment: Could you put your php url to test it, if it's possible of course ?

Comment: @akmozo here is the url https://www.kata-cloud.com/test.php

Comment: found the problem its working on flv video format. But video can be any other format. Is there any solution on how i can play any other video format?

Comment: You should know that flash can play only some video formats, for more details take a look on [my answer in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798605/playing-mpg-videos-in-flash-actionscript/27799581#27799581).

Comment: @akmozo thank you for the link.  it seems that other format is not working using appendbytes() unlike flv

Comment: Hi man, yes you are right, I forgot that you are using `ns.appendBytes`.