# Videos become mute when uploaded to webhost

Tags: html, flash, video

I am trying to embed a video with this code which works on videos hosted on other sites:

```
<object width="432" height="235">
<param name="movie" value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf">
</param>
<param name="flashvars" value="src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.one love %2Fdonate.mp4></param>    
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="432" height="235" flashvars="src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.booyah%2Fdonate.mp4"></embed></object>
```

The video plays fine, but there is no audio.  Locally, the mp4 file plays both audio and video.

I ftp the same video to the host and it losses audio.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong and how to get the sound back for this video on my website?

Comment: Maybe you disabled the sound of your browser?

Comment: It's enabled and plays other videos with sound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing your video with many tools like [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download), [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) and [MP4Box](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MP4Box), I found that the audio format of your video file is [**MPEG-1 Audio Layer II**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-1_Audio_Layer_II) (mp2) which is not supported by Flash Player that's why you can hear nothing when playing it with a Flash video player. I tested it with ffmpeg and ffprobe and both show it as mp3, so to be sure, I tested the video with a flash video player and I didn't see the audio metadata which can confirm that flash didn't support its audio format.

So for more details about video and audio formats supported by Flash Player, you can take a look on [my answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798605/playing-mpg-videos-in-flash-actionscript/27799581#27799581), and for more video tools and codec identifiers you can see [here](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/sections/codec-video-identifiers) and [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/determine-audio-video-codec-required-to-play-downloaded-movies/).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Cool so I need to re encode it, thanks.  Does mp3 work with flash?