# HTML video player in IE9 with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video-streaming

I've been looking for to long for a HTML video player which can load stream url's via Angular, and play them on IE9 ( via flash or whatever) on Chrome, FF, Mobile, ... via HTML5

I tried:

- videogular
- videoJS
- video-for-everyone
- sublimevideo
- ...

and looked on way to many pages for a working sollution. But couln't find any wich worked, I know this isn't the place to ask for a resource, documentation, file, ... But after searching for this long, this is prorbably the only place someone may know what I'm looking for

But for still asking a question for the player I got the most working:
that was the configuration on this page: http://www.realeyes.com/blog/2013/02/06/cross-browser-video-players/

this plays some videos but some uploaded videos (.mp4) won't play on chrome and FF

Comment: But why you didn't write your own code to play that video using HTML5 with Flash fallback or the inverse, normally it's just some lines ?

Comment: Because the HTML5 video player doens't play all the videos here, with some it says: file is corrupt, while IE9 plays it just fine

Comment: Of course, because HTML5 is supported from IE9 and up (for IE), and that's why you should use HTML5 with Flash fallback, so when a browser support HTML5, it can play it otherwise, it can play Flash.

Comment: that's true execpt the browsers that don't play the video are the latest version of FF and Chrome :)

Comment: Here, you should provide a supported format (H264, WEBM, OGG) for all possible browsers . Take a look on [my answer for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27995270/2256820) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27799581/2256820).

Comment: The company is using a serviio server for streaming the url, so that's the only option for formats I  have

Comment: The problem is not concerning the URL but the format (codec) of your videos, normally the server have nothing to do here, you can put any format that you want to use if the server support it (and I see that serviio supports many kind of videos). What is the format (and the codec) of your video which is not playing in Firefox and Chrome ?